# the first derivative of a complicated norm

Tags: derivatives

I would like to take the first derivative of a norm like this. I got the answer, but I am here to double check. Thank you.

$$\frac{d}{dx'}\left\{\exp\left[-\frac{\|x'-x\|^2} \theta \right]\right\},$$ where $\theta$ is a constant. $x'$ and $x$ are $1 \times p$ row vector, respectively.

Comment: 1) You'll get more useful answers if you show what your answer is and how you got it. 2) Hint: $\| x' - x \|^2 = (x' - x)^T (x' -x)$